# Why am I getting perfect on my decision tree ML algorithm training?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm testing out a Decision Tree for the first time and am getting a perfect score for my algorithm's performance. This doesn't make sense because the dataset that I am using is AAPL stock price for a bunch of different variables which obviously the algorithm can't detect perfectly.

CSV:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2010-01-04,10430.6904296875,10604.9697265625,10430.6904296875,10583.9599609375,10583.9599609375,179780000
2010-01-05,10584.5595703125,10584.5595703125,10522.51953125,10572.01953125,10572.01953125,188540000
```

I think the reason it might not be working is because I am essentially just feeding in the answers when training the model and it is just regurgitating those when I try and score the model.

Code:

```
# Data Sorting
df = pd.read_csv('AAPL_test.csv')
df = df.drop('Date', axis=1)
df = df.dropna(axis='rows')
inputs = df.drop('Close', axis='columns')
target = df['Close']

print(inputs.dtypes)
print(target.dtypes)

# Changing dtypes
lab_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
target_encoded = lab_enc.fit_transform(target)

# Model
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(inputs, target_encoded)

print(f'SCORE = {model.score(inputs, target_encoded)}')
```

I've also thought about randomizing the order of the CSV files, that could help but I'm not sure how I would do that. I could randomize the `df` at the top of the code but I'm pretty sure that, that would equally skew the results for both dataframes and therefore there would be no difference to what I am doing now. Otherwise, I could individually randmoize the datasets but I think that would mess with the model training or scoring because the test data won't be associated with the right data? I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably your model is overfitted. I think you did not split your dataset into two part: One is for training and the other is testing. Test data will help you to understand if your model overfit or underfit.

For more information:

[Overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting)

[How to Prevent Overfitting](https://towardsdatascience.com/8-simple-techniques-to-prevent-overfitting-4d443da2ef7d)